# Android Studio Rendering Problems: android.support.v4.view.ViewPager not found

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an XML layout containing `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager`.

The app works great when I run it, but the layout preview in Android Studio is unable to render this View, and shows the following error:

> Rendering Problems The following classes could not be found:
>
> - android.support.v4.view.ViewPager (Fix Build Path, Create Class)
>
> Tip: Try to build the project.

I have the following lines in `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
}
```

I have also tried adding `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'`, although some people seem to suggest that this is not needed since it is included in appcompat-v7. I am inclined to agree since the app works without it.

I have tried cleaning and rebuilding the project.

Comment: Views in support library are not rendering properly. From my experience.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with last Android Studio 1.2.1 update. I changed preview theme(to Material Dark) and now working good.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an "old" question, but if anyone get stuck, try to add this line into build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
```

Note that 22 stands to your api version, in this case (android 5.1).
Regards,